# How to convert a FASTA file to a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, biopython

I'm trying to transfer a .fasta file into a .xls file so that I can conveniently color my phylogenetic tree.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from Bio import SeqIO
s1 = {}
s2 = {}
with open('/Users/xxx.fasta') as seqF:
    for seqFP in SeqIO.parse(seqF,"fasta"):
        seq_id = seqFP.description
        seq_an = re.search(r"\[([^]]*)\]",seq_id)
        s1[seqFP.id] = seqFP.seq
        s2[seqFP.id] = seq_an
print(s2.values)
```

However when I tried to use the s1 to create a pd.Series, the sequence column shows like "(M, S, A, C, C, N, K, L, A, V, L, G, L, T, F, ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this FASTA file](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/WebSub/html/help/sample_files/nucleotide-sample.txt) as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import defaultdict


data = defaultdict(list)
with open('nucleotide-sample.txt') as fp:
  for record in SeqIO.parse(fp,"fasta"):
    organism = re.search(r"\[([^]]*)\]", record.description).group(1)
    sequence = str(record.seq)
    data['organism'].append(organism)
    data['sequence'].append(sequence)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Or, shorter but maybe less readable:

```
with open('nucleotide-sample.txt') as fp:
  records = [{'organism': re.search(r"\[([^]]*)\]", record.description).group(1), 
              'sequence': str(record.seq)} for record in SeqIO.parse(fp,"fasta")]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```

Both return the following DataFrame:

|  | organism | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | organism=Carpodacus mexicanus | CCTTTATCTAATCTTTGGAGCATGAGCTGGCATAGTTGGAACCGCCCTCAGCCTCCTCATCCGTGCAGAACTTGGACAACCTGGAACTCTTCTAGGAGACGACCAAATTTACAATGTAATCGTCACTGCCCACGCCTTCGTAATAATTTTCTTTATAGTAATACCAATCATGATCGGTGGTTTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCACTCATAATCGGCGCCCCCGACATAGCATTCCCCCGTATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTACTTCCCCCATCATTTCTTTTACTTCTAGCATCCTCCACAGTAGAAGCTGGAGCAGGAACAGGGTGAACAGTATATCCCCCTCTCGCTGGTAACCTAGCCCATGCCGGTGCTTCAGTAGACCTAGCCATCTTCTCCCTCCACTTAGCAGGTGTTTCCTCTATCCTAGGTGCTATTAACTTTATTACAACCGCCATCAACATAAAACCCCCAACCCTCTCCCAATACCAAACCCCCCTATTCGTATGATCAGTCCTTATTACCGCCGTCCTTCTCCTACTCTCTCTCCCAGTCCTCGCTGCTGGCATTACTATACTACTAACAGACCGAAACCTAAACACTACGTTCTTTGACCCAGCTGGAGGAGGAGACCCAGTCCTGTACCAACACCTCTTCTGATTCTTCGGCCATCCAGAAGTCTATATCCTCATTTTAC |
| 1 | organism=uncultured bacillus sp. | GGTAGGTACCGCCCTAAGNCTCCTAATCCGAGCAGAACTANGCCAACCCGGAGCCCTTCTGGGAGACGACCAAATCTACAACGTAGTCGTTACGGCCCACGCCTTCGTAATAATCTTTTTCATAGTAATGCCAATCATAATCGGAGGATTCGGGAACTGACTAGTTCCTCTAATGATTGGGGCCCCAGACATAGCATTCCCTCGAATAAACAACATAAGCTTTTGACTACTACCACCATCATTCCTACTCCTAATAGCCTCCTCAACAGTAGAAGCAGGAGCCGGAACCGGATGAACCGTGTACCCACCACTAGCTGGAAACCTGGCCCACGCCGGAGCCTCAGTAGACCTAGCTATCTTCTCCCTACACCTAGCAGGTATCTCATCCATCCTGGGGGCAATTAACTTCATTACAACAGCAATCAACATAAAACCACCCGCCCTCTCACAATACCAAACACCACTATTCGTGTGATCCGTCCTAATTACGGCCGTACTACTCCTACTATCTCTCCCAGTACTAGCCGCCGGTATCACCATGCTACTCACAGACCGCAACCTCAACACCACCTTCTTTGACCCAGCAGGAGGAGGAGACCCAGTACTATACCAGCACCTATTCTGATTCTTCGGACACCCAGAAGTCTACATCCTAATTCTC |
| 2 | organism=Phalaenopsis equestris var. leucaspis | CCTATACCTAATTTTCGGCGCATGAGCCGGAATGGTGGGTACCGCTCTAAGCCTCCTCATTCGAGCAGAACTAGGCCAACCCGGAGCCCTTCTGGGAGACGACCAAGTCTACAACGTGGTTGTCACGGCCCATGCCTTCGTAATAATCTTCTTTATAGTTATGCCGATTATAATCGGAGGATTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCCCTAATAATCGGAGCCCCAGACATAGCATTTCCGCGAATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTACTCCCACCATCATTCCTCCTCCTCTTAGCATCCTCCACAGTGGAAGCAGGCGTAGGTACAGGCTGAACAGTGTATCCCCCACTAGCTGGCAACCTAGCTCATGCCGGGGCCTCAGTCGACCTCGCAATCTTCTCCTTACACCTAGCTGGTATTTCCTCAATCCTCGGAGCAATTAACTTCATTACAACAGCAATTAACATGAAACCTCCTGCCCTCTCACAATACCAAACCCCACTATTCGTCTGATCAGTGTTAATTACTGCAGTCCTCCTTCTCCTTTCCCTTCCAGTTCTAGCTGCAGGAATCACAATGCTCCTCACAGACCGCAACCTCAACACCACATTCTTCGACCCTGCCGGAGGAGGAGATCCCGTCCTATATCAACATCTCTTCTGATTCTTCGGCCACCCAGAAGTCTACATCCTAATCCTC |
| 3 | organism=uncultured archaeon | CATGAGCTGGAATAGTAGGTACCGCCCTAAGCCTCCTAATTCGAGCAGAGCTAGGCCAACCCGGAGCCCTACTGGGAGACGACCAAATCTACAACGTAGTCGNCACGGCCCATGCTTTTGTAATAATCTTCTTCATAGTAATGCCAATCATAATCGGAGGGTTTGGAAACTGACTGGTCCCCCTAATAATTGGAGCTCCAGACATAGCATTCCCCCGAATAAACAACATGAGTTTCTGACTACTTCCCCCATCATTCCTACTACTAATAGCCTCCTCAACAGTAGAAGCAGGCGTTGGAACAGGATGAACCGTATATCCACCACTAGCCGGAAACCTAGCCCATGCAGGAGCCTCAGTAGACCTAGCTATCTTCTCCCTACACCTAGCAGGTATCTCCTCCATCCTAGGGGCAATCAACTTCATTACAACAGCAATCAACATAAAACCACCCGCCCTATCACAATACCAAACACCACTATTCGTATGATCCGTCCTAATCACAGCCGTACTACTCCTCCTATCACTCCCAGTGCTAGCTGCTGGAATTACCATGCTACTTACAGACCGCAACCTCAACACTACCTTCTTTGACCCAGCAGGGGGAGGAGACCCAGTGCTATACCAACATCTATTCTGATTCTTCGGACACCCAGAAGTTTACATCCTAATTCTC |
| 4 | organism=Influenza A virus | CCTATACCTAATTTTCGGCGCATGAGCCGGAATAGTGGGTACCGCCCTAAGCCTCCTCATTCGAGCAGAACTAGGCCAACCCGGAGCCCTTCTGGGAGACGACCAAGTCTATAACGTAGTTGTCACGGCCCATGCCTTCGTAATAATTTTCTTTATAGTTATGCCGATTATAATCGGAGGATTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCCCTAATAATCGGAGCCCCAGACATAGCATTCCCACGAATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTACTCCCACCATCATTCCTTCTCCTCCTAGCATCCTCCACAGTCGAAGCAGGCGTAGGTACAGGCTGAACAGTATACCCCCCACTAGCTGGCAACCTAGCTCACGCCGGAGCCTCAGTCGACCTCGCAATCTTCTCTCTACACCTAGCTGGTATTTCCTCAATCCTCGGAGCAATCAACTTCATTACAACAGCAATTAACATAAAACCTCCTGCCCTCTCACAATACCAAACCCCACTGTTCGTCTGATCCGTCCTAATCACTGCAGTCCTCCTGCTCCTTTCCCTTCCAGTTCTAGCTGCAGGAATCACAATACTCCTCACAGACCGCAACCTAAACACCACATTCTTCGACCCTGCTGGAGGAGGAGATCCCGTCCTATATCAACACCTTTTCTGATTCTTCGGCCACCCAGAAGTCTACATCCTAATCNTC |
| 5 | organism=Vireo gilvus | CATGAGCTGGAATAGTAGGTACCGCCCTAAGCCTCCTAATTCGAGCAGAGCTAGGCCAACCCGGAGCCCTACTGGGAGACGACCAAATCTACAACGTAGTCGTCACGGCCCATGCTTTTGTAATAATCTTCTTCATAGTAATGCCAATCATAATCGGAGGGTTTGGAAACTGACTGGTCCCCCTAATAATTGGAGCTCCAGACATAGCATTCCCCCGAATAAACAACATGAGTTTCTGACTACTTCCCCCATCATTCCTACTACTAATAGCCTCCTCAACAGTAGAAGCAGGCGTTGGAACAGGATGAACTGTATACCCGCCACTAGCCGGTAACCTAGCCCATGCAGGAGCCTCAGTAGACCTAGCTATCTTCTCCCTACACCTAGCAGGTATCTCCTCCATCCTAGGGGCAATCAACTTCATTACAACAGCAATCAACATAAAACCACCCGCCCTATCACAATACCAAACACCACTATTCGTATGATCCGTCCTAATCACAGCCGTACTACTCCTCCTATCACTCCCAGTGCTAGCTGCTGGAATTACCATGCTACTTACAGACCGCAACCTCAACACTACCTTCTTTGACCCAGCAGGGGGAGGAGACCCAGTGCTATACCAACATCTATTCTGATTCTTCGGACACCCAGAAGTTTACATCCTAATTCTC |
| 6 | organism=Pelecanus erythrorhynchos | TAGTTGGAACAGCCCTCAGCCTACTCATCCGAGCAGAACTAGGCCAACCCGGAACCCTCCTGGGAGATGACCAAATCTACAATGTAATCGTCACTGCCCATGCCTTCGTAATAATCTTCTTCATAGTAATACCAGTCATAATTGGAGGCTTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCCCTCATAATCGGCGCTCCAGACATAGCATTCCCACGTATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTCCTACCCCCATCCTTCCTACTCCTCCTAGCCTCATCCACAGTGGAAGCAGGCGCAGGAACAGGATGAACGGTGTACCCCCCACTAGCTGGCAACCTAGCCCATGCCGGAGCCTCAGTAGATCTAGCTATTTTCTCACTCCACTTAGCAGGGGTATCCTCTATTCTAGGTGCAATCAATTTCATCACAACCGCCATCAACATAAAACCACCAGCCCTATCACAATATCAAACTCCATTATTCGTGTGATCCGTACTCATCACTGCCGTCCTACTACTATTATCCCTCCCAGTCCTAGCCGCCGGCATCACTATGCTCCTCACAGACCGAAATCTGAACACTACATTCTTCGACCCCGCTGGAGGAGGAGACCCAGTCCTATACCAACACTTATTCTGGTTTTTCGGCCACCCAGAAGTTTACATCCTAATTCTC |
| 7 | organism=Hippodamia tredecimpunctata tibialis | TAGTTGGAACAGCCCTCAGCCTACTCATCCGAGCAGAACTAGGCCAACCCGGAACCCTCCTGGGAGATGACCAAATCTACAATGTAATCGTCACTGCCCATGCCTTCGTAATAATCTTCTTCATAGTAATACCAGTCATAATTGGAGGCTTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCCCTCATAATCGGCGCTCCAGACATAGCATTCACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTCCTACCCCCATCCTTCCTACTCCTCCTAGCCTCATCCACAGTGGAAGCAGGCGCAGGAACAGGATGAACGGTGTACCCCCCACTAGCTGGCAACCTAGCCCATGCCGGAGCCTCAGTAGATCTAGCTATTTTCTCACTCCACTTAGCAGGGGTATCCTCTATTCTAGGTGCAATCAATTTCATCACAACCGCCATCAACATAAAACCACCAGCCCTATCACAATATCAAACTCCATTATTCGTGTGATCCGTACTCATCACTGCCGTCCTACTACTATTATCCCTCCCAGTCCTAGCCGCCGGCATCACTATGCTCCTCACAGACCGAAATCTGAACACTACATTCTTCGACCCCGCTGGAGGAGGAGACCCAGTCCTATACCAACACTTATTCTGGTTTTTCGGCCACCCAGAAGTTTACATCCTAATTCTC |
| 8 | organism=Petunia integrifolia subsp. inflata | TAGTTGGAACAGCCCTCAGCCTACTCATCCGAGCAGAACTAGGCCAACCCGGAACCCTCCTGGGAGATGACCAAATCTACAATGTAATCGTCACTGCCCATGCCTTCGTAATAATCTTCTTCATAGTAATACCAGTCATAATTGGAGGCTTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCCCTCATAATCGGCGCTCCAGACATAGCATTCCCACGTATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTCCTACCCCCATCCTTCCTACTCCTCCTAGCCTCATCCACAGTGGAAGCAGGCGCAGGAACAGGATGAACGGTGTACCCCCCACTAGCTGGCAACCTAGCCCATGCCGGAGCCTCAGTAGATCCATCAACATAAAACCACCAGCCCTATCACAATATCAAACTCCATTATTCGTGTGATCCGTACTCATCACTGCCGTCCTACTACTATTATCCCTCCCAGTCCTAGCCGCCGGCATCACTATGCTCCTCACAGACCGAAATCTGAACACTACATTCTTCGACCCCGCTGGAGGAGGAGACCCAGTCCTATACCAACACTTATTCTGGTTTTTCGGCCACCCAGAAGTTTACATCCTAATTCTC |
| 9 | organism=Fusarium oxysporum f. tuberosi | TAGTTGGAACAGCCCTCAGCCTACTCATCCGAGCAGAACTAGGCCAACCCGGAACCCTCCTGGGAGATGAATTGGAGGCTTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCCCTCATAATCGGCGCTCCAGACATAGCATTCCCACGTATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTCCTACCCCCATCCTTCCTACTCCTCCTAGCCTCATCCACAGTGGAAGCAGGCGCAGGAACAGGATGAACGGTGTACCCCCCACTAGCTGGCAACCTAGCCCATGCCGGAGCCTCAGTAGATCTAGCTATTTTCTCACTCCACTTAGCAGGGGTATCCTCTATTCTAGGTGCAATCAATTTCATCACAACCGCCATCAACATAAAACCACCAGCCCTATCACAATATCAAACTCCATTATTCGTGTGATCCGTACTCATCACTGCCGTCCTACTACTATTATCCCTCCCAGTCCTAGCCGCCGGCATCACTATGCTCCTCACAGACCGAAATCTGAACACTACATTCTTCGACCCCGCTGGAGGAGGAGACCCAGTCCTATACCAACACTTATTCTGGTTTTTCGGCCACCCAGAAGTTTACATCCTAATTCTC |
| 10 | organism=Dendroica tigrina | TAGTTGGAACAGCCCTCAGCCTACTCATCCGAGCAGAACTAGGCCAACCCGGAACCCTCCTGGGAGATGACCAAATCTACAATGTAATCGTCACTGCCCATGCCTTCGTAATAATCTTCTTCATAGTAATACCAGTCATAATTGGAGGCTTCGGAAACTGACTAGTCCCCCTCATAATCGGCGCTCCAGACATAGCATTCCCACGTATAAACAACATAAGCTTCTGACTCCTACCCCCATCCTTCCTACTCCTCCTAGCCTCATCCACAGTGGAAGCAGGCGCAGGAACAGGATGAACGGTGTACCCCCCACTAGCTGGCAACCTAGCCCATGCCGGAGCCTCAGTAGATCTAGCTATTTTCTCACTCCACTTAGCAGGGGTATCCTCTATTCTAGGTGCAATCAATTTCATCACAACCGCCATCAACATAAAACCACCAGCCCTATCACAATATCAAACTCCATTATTCGTGTGATCCGTACTCATCAC |